# How to extract content from source generated by javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to extract content generated with javascript from a site. I cannot extract the data considering the source because the content in the page itself looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="java1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="java2.js"></script>
```

The content generated with those `java1.js` and `java2.js` so I need to extract the HTML source generated with these js scripts.

I can extract the content manually using Firefox by selecting the contents then right click then chose "view selection source", but I am looking for an automated solution with perl, python or whatever language that would be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[Win32::IE::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Win32%3A%3AIE%3A%3AMechanize&mode=dist)